# Consistent tabs through out the application

Tags: android, tabs

I have created an apk which has activities. I have included tabs in my program through which the user can select the required activity. But my main problem is that i couldnt find a way to display the tabs throughout the application. For example, on clicking a tab the corresponding tab opens. But when i click on a button the activity is displayed but the tabs are not getting displayed.

I have included a tabHost in the program to display the tabs for various activities...